# Radio Button link to URL on Submit

Tags: hyperlink, radio-button, form-submit

Hi this question has been asked before but the answer did not work for me. I have two radio buttons which, on submit, should direct the user to the corresponding URL, but the code I have only directs the user to the homepage, not the sub url.

Heres the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function doSubmit(form) {
   var urls = form['url'];
   var i = urls && urls.length;
   while (i--) {
   if (urls[i].checked) {
   window.location = urls[i].value;

  }
}
return false;
}
</script>

<moduleholder>
<module align="left" customid="0" width="auto" moduletype="ArtBox" moduleview="0">
<content hideifempty="True"></content>
<content hideifempty="False">
<module align="left" customid="0" width="auto" moduletype="Form" moduleview="0"       height="auto" usestandardstyles="True">
  <form onsubmit="return doSubmit(this)" action="">
    <input name="url" type="radio" value="http://www.google.com"> Google <input name="url" type="radio" value="http://www.yahoo.com"> Yahoo <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</module>
</moduleholder>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I have understood so far you have added two different radio buttons without validation between them; you either code them to be like:
Radio_button_1 : true
Radio_button_2 : !true

OR 
use Group Radio button to have same validation as better solution.

Comment: ok, I will try that, but I am a complete novice; is it easy to code? Regards

Comment: Yes of course, if you r doing visual programming it's just drag&drop then do ur codes, otherwise i'll bring u some useful links.

Comment: Ah, don't worry - i ditched that plan and went for 2 hyperlinks instead! Thanks though, anyway.